# An exercise from Ahlfors' book Complex Analysis

Tags: complex-analysis

this is Exercise 4, Section 3.2 (page 26) from Ahlfors book (First Edition):

**Show that any four distinct points can be carried by a linear transformation (i.e. Mobius transformation) to positions $1,-1,k,-k$, where the value of $k$ depends on the points? How many solutions are there, and how they related?**

My attempt: If the points are $z_1,z_2,z_3,z_4$, then it suffices to find a linear transformation $T$ such that
$$
\begin{cases}
T(z_1)+T(z_2)=0\\
T(z_3)+T(z_4)=0
\end{cases}
$$
Once we find such transformation, we can rotate and change proportion of its image to obtain the desired result. How to prove the existence of such transformation? and what is the answer of the rest of the question? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $S$ be the transformation mapping $z_1$, $z_2$, $z_3$ to $1$, $0$, $\infty$, respectively. Consider the transformation $T_k^{-1}$ mapping $1$, $0$, $\infty$ to $1$, $-1$, $k$. If we use the shorthand $z = (z_4, z_1, z_2, z_3)$, the problem reduces to finding a solution to the equation
$$
T_k (-k) = z
$$
as the desired transformations would then be of the form $T_k^{-1}S$.

If we plug in the expression for $T_k$, it comes down to solving the equation
$$
\frac{(-k)+1}{(-k)-k}\frac{1-k}{1+1} = z
$$
for $k$.